# Selecting all but latest 3 entries in DB

Tags: mysql

I have a page where the 3 latest entries in my db will be featured and all the older entries will be placed in another place...

i have this code for selecting the latest 3 entries:

```
SELECT
  release_id, release_pic, release_artist, release_title, release_info, 
  release_catalognr, beatportlink, ituneslink, traxsourcelink, alternativelink
FROM udgivelse
ORDER BY release_id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

But how would i go about selecting all the other entries for the other part of my side...? 
Meaning i want to start my selection from the 4th newest entry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM udgivelse";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$count= mysql_numrows($result);

$query2= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT release_id, release_pic, release_artist, release_title, release_info, release_tracks, release_catalognr, beatportlink, ituneslink, traxsourcelink, alternativelink FROM udgivelse ORDER BY release_id ASC LIMIT "+($count-3)+";) ORDER BY release_id DESC;"
```

Comment: but wont that flip my order around so i get entry nr 1 first? and not entry 97 (if i have 100 entries in total)

Comment: yes - but if we say it is being show at a site from top to bottom - then nr 97 should be at the top and nr 1 at the bottom - as the DESC is doing

Comment: If you don't want to flip them, then you can reorder them again by using a surrounding SELECT statement and order DESC again.

Comment: could you give an example of how i would nest a SELECT statement within another? :-) have never tried that before

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM udgivelse ORDER BY release_id ASC LIMIT count-3;) ORDER BY release_id DESC;

Comment: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT release_id, release_pic, release_artist, release_title, release_info, release_tracks, release_catalognr, beatportlink, ituneslink, traxsourcelink, alternativelink
    FROM udgivelse
    ORDER BY release_id
    ASC LIMIT count-3;) 
    ORDER BY release_id DESC;
    ";

it says i have an undefined variable: count? what am i missing...?

Comment: Did you save the count in a variable?

Comment: propably not? just copy/pasted what you wrote?

Comment: that gives me an error: Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/mmd3e12dae73/public_html/final/releases.php on line 19

Comment: Still not working :-( Now it says there is no connection to the DB...

 $dblink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*", "*", "*") or die ("...");
 $query= "SELECT * FROM udgivelse";
 $result= mysql_query($query);
        $count= mysql_numrows($result);

 $query2= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT (...) FROM udgivelse ORDER BY release_id ASC LIMIT "+$count-3+";) ORDER BY release_id DESC;";
      
 $oldrelease = mysqli_query($dblink, $query) or die("...");

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your `LIMIT 3` to like that:

```
 LIMIT 3,10   //--> this will select 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

--you can change the 10 as much you want get results after the the first 3 results
```

[here some reference](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

**EDIT.**

```
 ORDER BY release_id ASC LIMIT 3,10 ;
```

**EDIT**

Use the limit with a very high number as the second argument.

```
 limit 3,18446744073709551615;
```

From  [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

Comment: but its not the first the entries but the last 3 i want to count out.. meaning entry 11,12,13 if we go with your example :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple but not perfect way is to choose an improbably large number for the total possible number of rows and limit the query like this:

```
SELECT release_id, release_pic, release_artist, release_title, release_info, release_catalognr, beatportlink, ituneslink, traxsourcelink, alternativelink
                FROM udgivelse
                ORDER BY release_id DESC LIMIT 3, 10000000000;
```